# Firebase Android Default Setup and User Privacy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I followed the setup steps mentioned in Firebase docs in order to setup Firebase in my android app:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

However, after monitoring the outgoing http connections using Charles, I found the following URLs being accessed:

https://play.googleapis.com

https://www.googleapis.com

https://ssl.google-analytics.com

So my questions are:

1. Which of these URLs are used for Firebase analytics (I have read that Firebase analytics automatically collects information without doing any explicit call to Firebase analytics api)?
2. Is there any possibility to turn off sending information to Firebase? so I can control exactly the sent information for user privacy requirements? I have read in the documentation that it is possible to de-activate analytics by setting "firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" to true:
   https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics

So does setting this flag to true prevents automatic upload of data?

[image]

Comment: @Kenji this does not answer my question, I'm asking mainly about the URLs that are hitted when Firebase analytics is used (which is provided in Firebase client setup guide)? and If when turning off Firebase analytics, no other information is sent to Firebase servers? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Google Analytics for Firebase uploads events to https://app-measurement.com/a
2. Setting that flag prevents uploading of all events (whether automatically or manually logged).

Comment: Thanks Steve. So my remaining question is:

So does setting this flag to true prevents automatic upload of any other data by Firebase client (assuming that the app is utilizing the default Firebase setup which is described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)?